# How to determine size of page in uipageviewcontroller landscape?

Tags: xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I am working with the default UIPageViewController template from Apple. Basically just dabbling with it to learn how it works.

I would like to load a background image for the dataview controller and resize automatically it according to the orientation (rather than loading different images).

Is there any quick way I'm missing to determine the size of each page in landscape orientation? I don't mean

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame
```

which seems to give the size of the entire view including both pages, but rather the size of **one** of the two pages shown in landscape orientation. I've achieved more or less what I need with something like this

```
CGRectOffset(CGRectInset(self.pageViewController.view.bounds,125,0), -125, 0)];
```

but surely there must be some better way? This feels like an ugly hack.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I havent worked with the split view UIPageViewController yet, but as I understand it, you'd pass in two views which would be rendered as the two pages.  So why not let the page views determine the size of the graphic itself based on how the UIPageViewController has set it in the frame?